# Python, Raspberry, and Arduino Communication

Tags: python, arduino

I have been working with my Raspberry, Arduino and applying some Python to make them communicate.  I also installed pyserial. If I use IDLE and try the following I get my expected results.

```
  >>> import serial
  >>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',115200)
  >>> ser.write('!x:1\n')
  8
  >>> ser.readline()
  'X:1\r\n'
```

If I write a python scrip and run it I don't get anything back. Here is my python script.

```
  import serial
  ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)
  ser.write('!x:1\n')
  ser.readline()
```

I am new to Python so looking for some help to understand they this works in IDLE but not as a python script run from terminal.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you use `sudo` to run the script? For example: `sudo python myscript.py`

Comment: Yes, I am executing it like so...  sudo python test.py

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend to have the string in the third line of your script start with an exclamation point? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: Yes to the !. The arduino is looking for that as the start to the command I am sending it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this really came down to a timing issue.  The ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)  Needs to make the connection before sending any commands and the code I posted was just taking place too quick.